# RETURNN Librispeech Task: reused parameters of pretrained model for both LM and encoder-decoder model

Tags: returnn

I want to train RETURRN on LibriSpeech dataset reusing pretrained model of LM and encoder-decoder that has been offered on git, but don't know how to do. Is this possible? I don't see any option to enable it in .config file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible. The models can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn-experiments/tree/master/2018-asr-attention/librispeech/attention).

Do you just want to use the pretrained model for recognition? You don't need to do anything at all then. Just use it. Use the provided recognition scripts (see the paper, and the same repository).

Or do you want to train it further, using some additional data or so? In that case, this is also very simple. There is e.g. the option `import_model_train_epoch1`. But there are also related options, which you can use, depending on what you want to do exactly. See e.g. the comments in the code on `preload_from_files`.